# Should "file://~" be routed to "file://Users/userName"

Tags: file-io, url-routing

I've written a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) class which is also able to retrieve the content of an url. My question is the way it should handle the tilde `~` char within a file url.
In short: do I have to make `file://~` point to `file:///Users/userName` or it is something only related to the system's regular path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do this: `Start > Run > "file://~" (without quotes) > [OK]`

I get the following error message:

> [Window Title] file://~
>
> [Content] Windows cannot find 'file://~'. Make sure you typed the name
>   correctly, and then try again.
>
> [OK]

That said: The tilde `~` is a valid character for a filename under Windows.  I don't see why it should get any special treatment.

Comment: ok for windows, but on unix the tilde is a placeholder to the getenv("HOME") which returns the path of the home directory of the current user i.e. /Users/userName. This said, for cross compatibility purpose (as on window "~" is a valid char), it should in my opinion not be resolved to anything. Thanks